# How to give space between rating stars

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried this to make custom style for ratings

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">18dp</item>
    </style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff"  />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" />
</layer-list>
```

iam not getting space in between stars of rating bar.how can i achieve it.is there only way that i should give my star image padding.

Comment: If you have photoshop then add padding to that images you are using.

Comment: i don't have photoshop is there some other way

Comment: I don't think so. May be i am wrong but i have never used that type of padding.

Comment: ok thanks for help

Comment: May we see an picture? explaining where you miss the padding, and where you want it to be?

Comment: I have added a feature request, please vote for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230511